# uploading video file to ftp server from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

I am trying to upload my video file from my app to server and I am getting an exception in this code at uploadfilewitherror.

2014-08-22 15:55:49.092 [1990:907] -[__NSCFNumber localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f58fd60
2014-08-22 15:55:49.096 [1990:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f58fd60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x326ed2a3 0x3a36b97f 0x326f0e07 0x326ef531 0x32646f68 0x74bdd 0x7328f 0x32f82d41 0x32f7a5c1 0x32ff2be3 0x3a78311f 0x3a7824b7 0x3a783dcb 0x326c0f3b 0x32633ebd 0x32633d49 0x361e62eb 0x34549301 0x6fac3 0x6fa50)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

```
Code is as below.


 - (void)viewDidLoad
        { 
        [super viewDidLoad];
        ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] init];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
        } else {
            return YES;
        }
    }


    - (void) recordVideo {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
        picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
        picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        picker.videoMaximumDuration = 60;


        NSArray *sourceTypes = 
        [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType];
        if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie ]){
            NSLog(@"Can't save videos");
        }



        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];   
    }


    - (IBAction)startRecordClick:(id)sender {
        [self recordVideo];
    }



    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    }
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {



        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

        if (![mediaType isEqualToString:kUTTypeMovie])
            return;

        NSURL *mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSString* moviePath = mediaURL.absoluteString;
        NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        NSLog(@"filepath %@",tempFilePath);

        //try

        ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://"]
                                           toUploadFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tempFilePath" ofType:@"MOV"]];

        ftpRequest.username = @"";
        ftpRequest.password = @"";

        // Specify a custom upload file name (optional)
        ftpRequest.customUploadFileName = @"c.MOV";

        // The delegate must implement the SCRFTPRequestDelegate protocol
        ftpRequest.delegate = self;
        [ftpRequest startRequest];

        //try

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath))
        {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (tempFilePath, nil, nil, nil);   
        }

        [picker  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
        [picker release];

    }





    -(void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
        NSLog(@"Finished with error: %@", error);
    }

    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
        [picker  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
        [picker release];

    }


    - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{ 
    }
        - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

        }

    - (void)ftpRequestDidFinish:(SCRFTPRequest *)request {

        NSLog(@"Upload finished.");
    }

    - (void)ftpRequest:(SCRFTPRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

        NSLog(@"Upload failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    // Optional delegate methods
    - (void)ftpRequestWillStart:(SCRFTPRequest *)request {

        NSLog(@"Will transfer %lld bytes.", request.fileSize);
    }

    - (void)ftpRequest:(SCRFTPRequest *)request didWriteBytes:(NSUInteger)bytesWritten {

        NSLog(@"Transferred: %d", bytesWritten);
    }

    - (void)ftpRequest:(SCRFTPRequest *)request didChangeStatus:(SCRFTPRequestStatus)status {

        switch (status) {
            case SCRFTPRequestStatusOpenNetworkConnection:
                NSLog(@"Opened connection.");
                break;
            case SCRFTPRequestStatusReadingFromStream:
                NSLog(@"Reading from stream...");
                break;
            case SCRFTPRequestStatusWritingToStream:
                NSLog(@"Writing to stream...");
                break;
            case SCRFTPRequestStatusClosedNetworkConnection:
                NSLog(@"Closed connection.");
                break;
            case SCRFTPRequestStatusError:
                NSLog(@"Error occurred.");
                break;
            case SCRFTPRequestStatusNone:
                NSLog(@"Error occurred - NONE.");
                break;

        }
    }


    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code doesn't have any code base related to the FTP server.

`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate will trigger when you use/done a video selection from your picker controller. If you want to uploads the video to FTP at the same time without any button action, just use the below code.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


NSURL *mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
//search for FTP code samples and upload this NSData to the FTP.

    //save this video
    NSString *moviePath = [mediaURL path];

    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
    }

}
```

If you want an other action on the button which sends the video to the ftp server, save the Asset URL and retrieve the video files using `ALAsset` Url, convert this to strems and upload to FTP.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I am stuck with this requirement,i will try this method and get back to you.

Comment: ,How to get the videoURL of the recorded video?

Comment: i had done with my coding and i am getting an exception in the code,i had edited my question can you please go through the code and tell the changes i need to make.